Radial Mirror on Geometry Nodes, how to merge points from different copies?
So, I made a radial mirror on GN:


It works well, but it merges all points to all points, while I want to merge only points from one copy to other copies, like array modifier do. Is it a way to do this?

Unfortunately, the node Merge by Distance cannot do that, and I have missed it myself a few times. The only option is to skillfully select the points that are to be merged (in your case, possibly using Repeat Zone).

I have not looked deeply into this, but just as a thought, could you not assign the instance index as an attribute to the points somehow and only merge vertices that are from different instances? Although I just realized I do not know how to compare the vertices about to be merged with each other... but maybe there is a way I don't see right now.

the answer will be different with exact positioning (merge distance = 0) and with a threshold. Also reproducing possible quirks of the Array modifier may be tricky, because merging has some peculiar behaviors like "walking" that is, as points merge, distances between them change, merging is done in index order.

maybe this could help in some cases image

or this concept gif

although not sure it is viable gif blend

If you are modelling the symmetrical part manually, might as well assign an attribute to the boundary that needs to be merged manually. It's sometimes easy to get stuck wanting to do everything inside Geometry Nodes. I think it's worth considering if there is actually a good reason for that in your situation. I mean... there might be... But in some situation it might not be worth the trouble.

For now, I made an improvement in this task.
I have found a way that I can mark points that are has to be joined, but can't control how they join:

I look at closest points in neighbor copies and check if the distance is less than threshold.
